# Error: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed?

Tags: f#, ado.net

The following type is defined.

```
type DownloadedItem = { Period: DateTime; Name: string } with
    static member fromRdr(rdr:IDataReader) = 
        { Period = rdr.GetDateTime 0; Name = rdr.GetString 1 }
    static member asSeq (rdr:IDataReader) = seq { 
        while rdr.Read() do yield DownloadedItem.fromRdr rdr }
```

Then try to get data from database table.

```
let files =
    let sql = "exec [sp_name] @StartPeriod"
    use conn = new SqlConnection(Shared.connectionString)
    use cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartPeriod", SqlDbType.Date).Value <- StartPeriod
    conn.Open()
    use reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    reader
    |> DownloadedItem.asSeq
```

The above expression can be sent to F# interactive window without any problem.

However, evaluate `files;;` got the following error?

```
val it : seq<DownloadedItem> =
  Error: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.
```

Comment: what if you make `files` a function? `let files() = ...` Now it's a static binding in some temporary module and the initialization can be tricky... and you have `use` bindings inside it.

Answer (score 2):

Sequences are lazy. This means that a sequence does not get evaluated until somebody tries to get at its elements.

Try this:

```
let s = seq {
   for i in 1..1000 do
       printfn "%d" i
       yield i
}

> Seq.take 3 s
```

This program only prints numbers from 1 to 3, even though the definition of the sequence says 1000. This is because the `Seq.take 3` call only enumerates the first three elements of the sequence, and the evaluation does not proceed further.

Now lets go another step:

```
let s = 
    printfn "Creating sequence"
    let result = seq { printfn "Returning item"; yield 42 }
    printfn "Done creating sequence"
    result
```

Executing this code prints "Creating sequence", then "Done creating sequence". But it does not print "Returning item" at all. Why not? We have *constructed* the sequence, but never *evaluated* it. Now if I execute `s`, then "Returning item" will be printed.

See what's happening? The body of `s` finished executing *before* the resulting sequence is evaluated.

The same thing happens in your code: the body of `files` finishes executing before the resulting sequence is evaluated. And when the body of `files` finished executing, the `reader` gets disposed, since it was bound with `use`. Therefore, by the time you get to *evaluating* the sequence, `reader` is no longer valid, so you get the error.

---

To fix this, you need to make sure that `reader` is kept valid the whole time the sequence is being evaluated. The only practical way to do that is include all the `use`s in the body of the sequence:

```
let files = seq {
    let sql = "exec [sp_name] @StartPeriod"
    use conn = new SqlConnection(Shared.connectionString)
    use cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartPeriod", SqlDbType.Date).Value <- StartPeriod
    conn.Open()
    use reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    while rdr.Read() do yield DownloadedItem.fromRdr reader
}
```

This way, the whole initialization happens every time somebody tries to enumerate the sequence, and the `reader` is kept valid until the enumeration is finished.